# Creating a simple bar graph with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am attempting to create a basic bar graph using matplotlib that displays data for a reddit bot that returns the top 10 words used out of all your comments. Its y-axis being the number of times used and the x-axis being the word. However, I am a complete noob and I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

To be more specific. The function that creates the graph takes in a dictionary in the format {'word': number of times used}. Any help would be very much appreciated.

EDIT: got it

```
 def graph_data(self, data):
    words = []
    occurence = []

    for k,v in data.items():
        words.append(k)
        occurence.append(v)

    s = sum(occurence)
    N = 10 # scale. 
    ind = np.arange(N)
    width = 0.35 
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    g = ax.bar(ind, occurence, width, color='r')

    ax.set_ylabel('Occurences')
    ax.set_title('Words')
    ax.set_xticks(ind+width)
    ax.set_xticklabels(words)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have a look at this demo: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

Comment: Many examples available: http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/ try some of them

Comment: Hey, I added an edit. Using the demo I wrote that. However I am getting this error: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 13 or scalar

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a limit

```
def graph_data(self, data):
    words = []
    occurence = []

    for k,v in data.items():
        words.append(k)
        occurence.append(v)

    s = sum(occurence)
    N = 10 # scale. 
    ind = np.arange(N)
    width = 0.35 
fig=plt.figure(v,k)
ax=plt.axes(xlim=(0,10),ylim=(1,5))
line,=ax.plot([],[],lw=2)
def init():
    line.set_data([],[])
    return line,


def animate(i):

    #print x 
    line.set_data(set,beds[i])
    return line,




plt.show()
```